# Rust Function Returning a Generic Type

Tags: rust, traits

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

fn main() {
    pub type KG = u32;

    #[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug, Clone, Copy)]
    pub struct Pound(pub u32);

    impl From<Pound> for KG {
        fn from(p: Pound) -> Self {
            p.0 / 45
        } 
    }
    
    impl From<KG> for Pound {
        fn from(k: KG) -> Self {
            Self(k * 45)
        }
    }

    pub trait Matter {
        /// The output unit of the energy density.
        type Output: Into<KG> + From<KG>;
    
        /// The amount of mass contained in a single unit of matter.
        fn density() -> Self::Output;
    }


    pub struct Iron;
    impl Matter for Iron {
        type Output = Pound;
        fn density() -> Self::Output {
            Pound::from(7800)
        }
    }

    pub struct MatterContainer<M: Matter> {
        volume: u32,
        _marker: PhantomData<M>,
    }

    impl<M: Matter> MatterContainer<M> {
        pub fn new(volume: u32) -> Self {
            Self {
                volume,
                _marker: Default::default(),
            }
        }
    }

    pub trait GetWeight<M: Matter> {
        /// Get the weight of Matter in `m`
        /// This method must be provided as it will be the same in all implementations.
        fn get_weight(&self, m: MatterContainer<M>) -> <M as Matter>::Output {
            todo!()
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a code where get_weight function gets the weight of the matter container generally by multiplying the density of the matter over the volume of the container, but as for different matters the density is given in different units(in this example Iron density is in pounds, but for other materials it could be ounces for example(which is not implemented here for the sake of the simplicity of the given issue)), the return type is a generic Output type. How could I implement it without changing the signature of get_weight function?
thank you

Comment: I suggest you just use the given bounds, specifically `Output: Into<KG> + From<KG>`.

Comment: @cafce25 thanks for the response, could you please provide a code snippet for it?

Comment: The code you provided has a number of issues preventing it from compiling as-is (for example, dividing a u32 by a float). Could you please fix those errors?

Comment: @AndersEvensen thanks for the response, the issues that you have told about is solved now. Could you look at the code again?

Comment: `(M::density() * m.volume).into()`

Comment: Btw, I'm not sure why would you want to return the density of each kind of matter in a different unit. Can't you instead create a `Weight` type which has methods for converting from/to kilograms, pounds, ounces, etc.? Also, what do you want to implement `GetWeight` for?

Comment: Hey @FZs your solution works with a slight improvement(you also have to change density.into() as the compiler does not let multiply Output by u32). Regarding your last question, it can be simplified in a simpler way, its just a sort of exercise for mastering traits;) thank you;)

Comment: @AdesojiAlu The problem is already solved. Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
(M::density().into() * m.volume).into()
```

Comment: please update your answer with more than just code, to include an explanation so that this answer can help others in the future.